# PHP function to get new month year

Tags: php, mysql

newbie here at a small non-profit. I inherited a website written long ago and trying to update it. I need help. This page is to insert hyperlinks to forms for entering monthly data. Until now the website was automatically populated with current month and year hyperlinks. Now it is stuck on April 2014. I don't see anywhere in the Mysql tables or code to add the new months. I believe it may be the 'function getNewMonth($x)' but I don't know why it stopped working. I need to get May in there! 
Thanks in advance.

```
    function getNewMonth($x)
{
   global $database_fvca, $fvca, $myid, $legacyprint;
   mysql_select_db($database_fvca, $fvca);
   $sql = "SELECT instid FROM instance WHERE reportyear=".date("Y", $x)." AND reportmonth=".date("n", $x).
          " AND orgid=".$myid;
   $q = mysql_query($sql);
   $n = mysql_num_rows($q);
   if ($n == 0)
   {
          return '<td><a href="monthstart.php?orgid='.$myid.'&month='.date("n", $x).'&year='.
                 date("Y", $x).'">begin</a></td><td>&nbsp;</td>';
   }
   else
   {
          $a = mysql_result($q,0);
          return '<td><a href="editmonth.php?instid='.$a.'">edit</a></td><td><a href="viewmonth.php?instid='.$a.
                 '">view report</a></td>'; } }
       function getMonth($date)
{
```

Comment: What is setting `$x`?

Comment: That is the first instance.

Comment: The first instance of what?

Comment: Note that this is (of course) really old code, using a deprecated API. We just don't do it like this anymore. Would it be too much to start from scratch?

Comment: Sorry Jay, not sure, first time it comes up in the code.

Comment: Strawberry, yes the code must be a flashback. Too much for me to start over, maybe hire somebody soon. For now I'd just like to buy some time and get May and June in there.

Comment: is it possible that the PHP version of the website was upgraded and some of this code is no longer supported? so now the new months are not populated.

Comment: It ending in april is useful in that it is normally to do with financial / tax years. Look at the 'admin' screens for current financial year. The database will be a clue as there will be a 'driving' dates table that there are foreign keys to. Search the code for queries involving tables with dates. Look at the screen / forms and see where they get their dates from.